# SQL Server xcopy and xp_cmdshell file not found

Tags: sql-server

I read other help posts but I keep getting file not found on the the network.  The path is on the network on a fileshare and I'm using RDP to remote to my own machine that connects to the SQL Server database.

I'm using xcopy command with xp_cmdshell. I can't use just "copy" because I get an access denied error so I'm using Xcopy in this format:

```
echo f|xcopy /i "\\fileserver\file\excelfile1.xls" \\fileserver\file\newdirectory\excelfile1.xls"
```

I have tried almost everything and read other posts but this is still not working.  I do have parameters for the directory and files, etc. but I actually have it hard-coded in the dos command it's still not working.

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: I have also RDP into the actual SQL Server machine that it's running on and this network path is valid..maybe I need to execute the sproc as a different user but I'm not getting a permissions issue just file not found.

Comment: Do you have a proxy account for xp_cmdshell configured?

Comment: Can you post the exact text of the errors you are receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an "access denied" with `copy`, you'll get the very same error with `xcopy` too. It offers more options, but won't let you bypass the OS security at will, both are still bound to the permissions of the user account that runs them, like every other software.

There are two options:

Use [sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190359.aspx) to specify a different user for all xp_cmdshell operations (as suggested by *Bacon Bits*). This user must have enough permissions to both origin and target files.

Give those permissions to the account that runs the SQL Server service, so that it can access the files directly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank  you everyone for responding.  This is the first time I've used this forum.

I found out the files were named .XLS but actually in .TXT delimited format.  So I renamed them through SSIS with a ForEach Loop and processed them from there.

I tried to XCOPY from command line with new permissions that that didn't work.  I was getting an extension hardening error and that is why, XLS to TXT wasn't liking it.

Comment: I was also having major security issues running as different user on the network and using sprocs.  That may have been the issue too.